# While reading two array in c through scanf, the second one somehow modify the first

Tags: c, string, input, scanf

I have the following problem reading two strings through `scanf`: I insert the first string and everything it's OK, but after I insert the second one the first one changes.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 6
#define K 2

int main(){
    char a[N];
    char b[K];
    int i = 0,j=0;
    printf("first word\n\n\n");

    scanf("%s", a);
    for(i = 0; i <= N; i++){
        printf("%c", a[i]);
    }

    printf("second word \n\n\n");

    scanf("%s", b);
    for(i = 0; i <= N; i++){
        printf("%c", a[i]);
    }
}
```

The first time it prints it correctly. The second time it prints a similar string (maybe the first `scanf` is still getting the input when I'm inserting the second one)

Comment: Obviously the inputs that I tried where respecting the dimensions of the arrays

Comment: what are you inputs you entered for both scanf?

Comment: yea don't mind the j, this is only a part of the code. The problem is in the array a, this is why I wrote the second loop with a[i], the array b is well printed.

Comment: "Obviously the inputs that I tried where respecting the dimensions of the arrays."-- Is this true? `for(i = 0; i <= N; i++)` suggests that you have forgotten about null-terminators.

Comment: Perhaps `for(i = 0; a[i] && i < N; i++){...}`

Comment: @Pras, abcabc  and abc .

Comment: These inputs do _not_ respect array dimensions. See [`@xing`s suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44614118/while-reading-two-array-in-c-through-scanf-the-second-one-somehow-modify-the-fi#comment76214728_44614118); you should _always_ specify maximum widths when using `%s` with `scanf()` to avoid buffer overflow.

Comment: @xing this made the trick. Sorry for the stupid question and thank you all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin, you are printing the array `a` twice; it seems that you mean to print `b` with the second loop. But there is a problem in your loops. They are going out of array bounds. Since arrays are zero-indexed in C, you need:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {}
```

for `a`, and:

```
for (i = 0;i < K; i++) {}
```

for `b`.

But even this is not quite right, since the input strings may not entirely fill the arrays. You really need to terminate the loop when the null-terminator is reached, or when the end of the array has been reached:

```
for (i = 0; a[i] != '\0' && i < N; i++) {}
```

and:

```
for (i = 0; b[i] != '\0' && i < K; i++) {}
```

Of course, it would be simpler to just use `puts()` to print the strings.

It seems that the inputs [(`abcabc` and `abc`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44614118/while-reading-two-array-in-c-through-scanf-the-second-one-somehow-modify-the-fi#comment76214730_44614118) were too large for the arrays, causing buffer overflow. This can be avoided by specifying maximum widths when using the `%s` conversion specifier with `scanf()`.

Here is a modified version of the posted code. I increased the sizes of `N` and `K` by one, since it appears that space for null-terminators was not considered in the original code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 7
#define K 3

int main(void)
{
    char a[N];
    char b[K];
    int i = 0;

    printf("first word\n\n\n");

    scanf("%6s", a);
    for (i = 0; a[i] != '\0' && i < N; i++) {
        printf("%c", a[i]); 
    }
    putchar('\n');

    printf("second word \n\n\n");

    scanf("%2s", b);
    for (i = 0; b[i] != '\0' && i < K; i++) {
        printf("%c", b[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are printing `a` twice, change the second  `printf("%c", a[i]);` to `printf("%c", b[i]);` .

Comment: Also better change to: `for(i = 0; i < N; i++)` for `a`, and: `for(i = 0; i < K; i++)` for `b` to avoid undefined behavior.

Comment: You're right, I did not notice it.

Answer (score 1):

For the second `printf` you have to write

```
printf("%c", b[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are experiencing is *because you invoke undefined behavior* by failing to insure the strings are *nul-terminated* and by using incorrect limits regarding `b`. For instance, you

```
#define N 6
#define K 2
...
    char a[N], b[K];
```

`a` can hold a total of `5-chars` + *the nul-terminator*, for a total of `6-chars`. `b` on the other hand, can only hold `1-char` + *the nul-terminator* for a total of `2-chars`.

When you then subsequently loop of both `a` and `b` with `for(i = 0; i <= N; i++)`, not only have you guaranteed to access an element outside the bounds of the array, e.g. `a[6]` (valid indexes are `0-5`), you have also invoked undefined behavior for any `a` with less that 6 total characters by attempting to read from an uninitialized value (those uninitialized array elements after the last valid char in word of say, `3-chars`) When you invoke *Undefined Behavior*, the execution of your code is unreliable from that moment forward.

In your case you can eliminate undefined behavior by using *field width* modifiers to limit the number of characters placed in the arrays by `scanf` itself, e.g.

```
    if (scanf ("%5s", a) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input - a.\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

You **validate** the return of `scanf` to insure the proper number of conversions have taken place, or you handle the error if they have not.

You prevent reading beyond the bounds of the array by limiting your read and output char loop to only valid characters within the array. You do that by checking the character to be printed is not the *nul-terminating* character, and when the *nul-terminating* character is reached, you exit the loop without attempting to print it.

Putting those pieces together, you could do something similar to the following (note `j` is unused in your code so it is commented out):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 6
#define K 2

int main (void ) {

    char a[N], b[K];
    int i = 0/*, j = 0*/;

    printf ("enter first word: ");
    if (scanf ("%5s", a) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input - a.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; a[i] && i < N; i++)
        printf ("%c", a[i]);
    putchar ('\n');

    printf ("enter second word: ");

    if (scanf ("%1s", b) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input - b.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; b[i] && i < N; i++)
        printf ("%c", b[i]);
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/twowords
enter first word: cats
cats
enter second word: dogs
d
```

I would strongly caution you to consider reading line-oriented input with a line-oriented input function like `fgets`. This eliminates many pitfalls for new programmers. The only additional step when using `fgets` is to recall it reads up-to-and-including the trailing `'\n'`, so you need to trim the `'\n'` from the string read.

Look things over an let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

As per inputs(abcabc and abc ) you mentioned your are providing to scanf are causing overflow for both the variables a and b,
You should enter string of length 5 for first and 1 for second keeping space for `\0` for both the strings

Edit: Also change loop condition from `i <= N` to `i<N` or `i<sizeof(a)`. 
Please note the loop will print garbage characters past string length if the length of string happens to be less than 5

Comment: This won't matter since OP loops go out of array bounds anyway....

Comment: True, added and edit for that

Answer (score 0):

I see two things that you can do here:

1. Use another big buffer array that you will load data to, and that copy data to specyfic array. Than you will get max 6 letters of first word in a[], and max 2 letters of second word in b[]. But you will be able to load 2 words.
2. Scanf specyfic amount of chars like @xing mentiond in comment.

`scanf("%6s",word)` //general use, not in OP's case

Than when you've got longer word than size that you set up, you will have the rest of input as input in second word.

Comment: This is not the correct width specifier for OP's `#define N 6`.

Comment: It was just general example, not for OP's case. I even did not use 'a' as argument.

Comment: Well, that is just confusing....

Comment: I think that not at all. It could be in case I used name of argument from his code.

Comment: It is confusing because OP uses 6 for `N`. Why would you arbitrarily choose 6?

Comment: I've commented it. If it was confusing for you it can be for someone else, so thanks for attention.